# Is the commonly assumed UFO (flying saucer) design aerodynamically efficient?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics

[image: A UFO]

Is this design, a circular disc (or flying saucer) slightly humped on the top and bottom aerodynamically efficient? And if, we are able to use it for commercial purposes , would they give a better efficiency than existing aircraft?

This [article](http://www.gizmag.com/go/7710/) states that this would be a better design. Is this true?

Comment: I am just an enthusiast, who is pretty familiar with physics. But, still please keep your answers little simple..!!

Comment: That article does NOT state it would be a better design. In outer space there is no aerodynamics as there is no air. If you are familiar with physics then how is the design going to generate lift?  You do have many interesting questions but this one is bit out there.

Comment: @Blam Just about any shape can generate lift if it can accelerate air downwards.  [The Canadian Avrocar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avro_Canada_VZ-9_Avrocar) is an example of a disc which generates lift, as is a Frisbee.  Whether it's efficient or not is a separate matter.

Comment: @Simon Agreed. A brick can fly if you propel it fast enough. Most fighter aircraft are proof of that. I disagree that this question is really off-topic. This one may be a little odd, but questions about aerodynamics are explicitly on-topic here.

Comment: Would the aliens care? It only needs to be efficient design for hyperspace/warp travel; they don't care about the last 100km or so.

Comment: @Blam I am not talking about space. Just the atmosphere (troposphere/stratosphere).

Comment: OH just a local home built UFO designed to stay close to home.  Again nothing in that article states a better design.  Why sensationalize and misstate?

Comment: @Blam: Lift is irrelevant, since the "flying saucer" type of UFO presumably has anti-gravity & a reactionless drive :-)

Comment: I'm guessing the efficiency of a (non-rotating) disc like this wouldn't be very high, on its own; because the "wings" are effectively of very low aspect ratio, and there would probably be quite a lot of induced drag from the "wingtips" at normal speeds. But using this profile on the body of a blended wing design with more conventional wings would be a completely different matter. Any proper aerodynamicists in the house?

Comment: @anshabhi I edited one of my answers from a month ago with a picture and reasons why it wouldn't be efficient. I think it is a very good question.

Comment: In (all?) sci fi this is backed up with some exotic propulsion system, such as anti-gravity, etc.  This design would not serve much of a use for us Earth folk.

Comment: @Ethan sorry.. I am just very less active on Stack Exchange these days and and further I don't get any notifications if someone edits their answer on one of my questions.

Comment: @Ethan you have put some very sincere efforts in writing the answer.. And, I salute them!

Comment: @MartinJames becaue a spacecraft needs to be able to return safely to its home planet which almost certainly has an atmosphere. A reusable spacecraft that doesn't blast off like a rocket would need lift to get off the ground and get up to speed before going with throttle up to reach escape velocity(or at least orbital velocity).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The correct answer is no. A ufo with its circular shape has trouble traveling through the air. It struggles to travel through the air like a city bus, which  gets 2-6mpg. Depending on the amount of thrust this object has depends whether it can lift up into the air. But it would not be efficient because of the amount of fuel it needs to consume to pass through the air, its kind of like a flying city bus not really very aerodynamic and is terrible in efficiency. If this was powered by human technology it would not be efficient considering if its made by humans, if it was made by aliens then maybe it would be efficient, but that information we do not know and probably never find out in our lifetime and we don't even know if aliens exist. You also have to consider the design of this certain ufo. This shape cannot develop lift and runs fully on thrust, which also decreases its efficiency because of gravity pushing down on the flying object. Imagine an airliner without wings and how much efficiency you loose without the wings.[image]Wind tunnel test for a circular shape. If a ufo was so efficient it would have been used on our current airliners. Now lets go into problems with a ufo being an airliner.

1. Its round circular shape would have trouble fitting into modern day terminals
2. Much thrust needed for vertical takeoff and landings
3. Not much room to store fuel
4. It would be very difficult for pilots to fly this object compared to modern day airliners
5. Airports would be redesigned for these objects which costs billions of dollars
6. Only has one engine to push the object instead of generally 2 on an airliner
7. Lots of weight the one engine needs to lift
8. One engine would be very difficult to do maintenance work on
9. The amount of money needed to be invested into this type of airliner
10. No horizontal or vertical stabilizer
11. Cost even more than the Concorde for maintenance
12. The costs to buy one of these would be 5x the price of a regular airliner
13. Amount of gas needed would be more than the Concorde
14. Amount of money needed to invest in this kind of technology, which doesn't even exist yet
15. No airline would want this because of the price
16. The whole ufo would generate lift, but that technology already exists and that's called a blended wing body, which is more of the focus towards future airliner and already has lots of money invested into it, and investing in a ufo would be too much money considering the amount invested blended wing body designs.

So I hope those 16 reasons helped explain why it would not be more efficient  than a modern day airliner and why it can't go into service. So the article was false for efficiency and other reasons.

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to say.

Comment: I'm saying that they have tested a mini circular shaped model like a ufo in a wind tunnel and it wasn't very aerodynamic, if it used fossil fuels to power the aircraft it would not be efficient at all it would take a lot of fuel to power the ufo.

Comment: @Ethan Who said there was a correlation between time spent and quality of output? Rather than spend time listing everything that goes through your head, try to make sure that what you write is understandable to other people. But keep up the good work, your contributions to this community are overall getting better and better :)

Comment: @usernumber Thanks I will try to make every answer have this much thought and correct grammar mistakes so people can understand it. I took my old answer deleted everything and wrote a whole new answer thats more understandable and having  greater details.

Comment: @mins you know there is evidence of life once existing on mars. Weird figure shaped rocks have been found. I do believe this because mars did once have water and this society could have buried there kind into rocks so that another species could someday see it.

Comment: @Ethan There is no evidence of life on Mars.  There are some indicators that there **might** be evidence to be found but so far, none has.

Answer (score -2):

They use the concept of VTOL thats vertical Take off and Landing. [Click here to know more about VTOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VTOL)

Regarding the efficiency, well I think no one can give a 100% perfect information on this because, we do not know the fuel used, the engineering behind the structure. There are a lot of factors affecting efficiency like :
Materials, Fuel, Type of Engine, Weight etc. So aerodynamics alone cannot judge the efficiency of the aerovehicle. 
Thanks!

Comment: `So aerodynamics alone cannot judge the efficiency of the aerovehicle.` but the question specifically asks about the *aerodynamic* efficiency, not the overall efficiency.